# Currency code is scarab (¤) for es-419

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

**---- UPDATE March 28, 2017 ----**

When you set the language and region for the app via "Edit Scheme" in Xcode, you get the combined locale identifier of `es-419_MX`. However, when you change the actual language and region of the device/simulator by going into the settings, you get the "correct" locale identifier `es_MX`, while maintaining the language code of `es-419`, which effectively solves the issue for almost every use case.

```
// After setting language and region in Edit Scheme from Xcode
print(Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations) // ["es-419", "es"]
print(Locale.current) // es-419_MX (current)

// After setting the language and region from Settings
print(Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations) // ["es-419", "es"]
print(Locale.current) // es_MX (current)
```

**---- /UPDATE ----**

I'm localizing my app into Latin American Spanish (`es-419`). When I try to display a localized currency using the `NumberFormatter`, iOS returns a scarab `¤` instead of a dollar sign `$`.

For example, if the user's region is Mexico, they will have the region code `es-419_MX`. Instead of returning `$`, the following code returns `¤`

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es-419_MX")
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencySymbol // ¤
```

If I remove the "419", I get the proper currency symbol:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_MX")
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencySymbol // $
```

Is it possible to get the correct currency symbol when `Locale.current` returns `es-419_MX`? Or will I have to resort to a hack where I remove instances of `419` from the locale code?

Actual code:

```
func localizedCurrency(value: Double) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value)) ?? "$\(value)"
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about latin american spanish, but  http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-419/index.html lists "¤" as currency symbol.

Comment: What is the 419 from?

Comment: `es-419` is the code for Spanish - Latin America.

Comment: But why use such a vague locale? On a typical iOS device a user will set their language and a country giving a more specific locale such as `es_MX` or `es_CO`, etc.

Comment: Localizing for `es-419` should handle translations for most regions in Latin American (instead of localizing for each specific country)

Comment: What translations are you referring to? You are talking about number (currency) formatting. There is no reason at all to generalize that to some vague "Latin American" locale. Using the device's current locale lets the user see numbers and dates in their familiar format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do the hack, or you'll have to be specific for each country.

Since `es_419` is a generic specification for all Latin American countries, it can't "guess" that you want a `$` to display.

Different countries under the `es_419` locale "parent" have different currency character standards. For example, Bolivia's currency symbol is `Bs`.

[ICU Locale “Spanish (Bolivia)” (es_BO)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-BO/index.html)

Comment: Bummer. I guessed as much but it still feels wrong.