# WinForms DataGridView Currency Formatted Column Shows Scarab (¤) Instead of Local Symbol ($)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, currency-formatting

I have a couple of WinForms apps that use datagridviews to display currency fields.  I set the columns as currency in this manner:

```
dgv.Columns["Cost"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
```

However, it seems that after the app has been open for a while, the dollar sign "$" will switch to a scarab (¤).

[image]

Once this happens, the user needs to restart the app, and then it will work again for some random amount of time.  Is there any way that I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: The scarab is a symbol for currency when culture is ambiguous, perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography). Is the culture changing for the app anywhere?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43007653/832052) dealt with a similar issue, where the culture was being set to a locale which covered multiple principalities with varying currency symbols. In that case `es-419_MX`, which covers multiple principalities, vs. `es_MX`